# Azure Functions suddenly getting Entry Point was not found error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

We currently have a deployed app to Azure functions, created with Visual Studio, that now all of a sudden started returning an exception on calling the HTTP function of "Entry Point was not found". The worst part is that the local Azure function runs fine making debugging a nightmare. Has anybody gotten this problem and possibly a fix? The Function.json file has a endpoint assigned and everything looks fine in the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

So after updating all the Nuget packages with the latest Azure SDK's and doing another publish, the issue seems to be resolved.